# QApplication::postEvent правильно ли?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Есть класс наследник QWidget, у которого есть виртуальный метод updateStyle(). Данный метод должен срабатывать при получение QEvent::StyleChange и один раз при конструирование формы. Просто вызвать виртуальный метод и конструктора класс нельзя, так как класс-наследник еще не создан. Чтоб это обойти я воспользовался методом QApplication::postEvent, в данном случае срабатывает updateStyle() класса-наследника как и задумывалось. Вопрос в том, на сколько корректен этот код? всегда ли будет нужное мне поведение?

extendedwidget.h

```
class ExtendedWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    ExtendedWidget(QWidget *_parent = 0);

    virtual void updateLanguage();
    virtual void updateStyle();

protected:
    virtual void changeEvent(QEvent *event) override;
};
```

extendedwidget.cpp

```
ExtendedWidget::ExtendedWidget(QWidget *_parent):
    QWidget(_parent)
{
    QApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(QEvent::StyleChange));
}

void ExtendedWidget::updateLanguage()
{

}

void ExtendedWidget::updateStyle()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
}


void ExtendedWidget::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->type())
    {
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        updateLanguage();
        break;
    case QEvent::StyleChange:
        updateStyle();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    QWidget::changeEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну в эту ситуацию Qt лучше не привлекать, эта проблема довольно частая и решается она обычно в явном виде, пишете какой-нибудь

```
virtual void init() ;
```

и вызываете его всегда сразу после конструктора, примерно так

```
ExtendedWidget *w = new ExtendedWidget;
w->init();
```

imho лучше способов для этого в c++ нет